# Covariance matrix in multivariate standard normal density

Tags: probability, statistics, variance, covariance

I am looking at the derivation of $f_{\vec{Y}}(\vec{y})$ where  $\vec{Y}=A \vec{X}$ and $\vec{X}$  is a vector of i.i.d **standard normal random variables**. $A$ is an $n \times n$ non-singular matrix.

The multivariate standard normal density is given by :

$$f_{\vec{X}}(\vec{x})=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\right)^{n} \exp \left[-\frac{1}{2} \vec{x}^{\top} \vec{x}\right]$$

And by the change of variables theorem ;

$$f_{Y}(y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}f_{X}(h(Y))\left|J_{h}(y)\right| & \text { for } y \in R \\ 0 & \text { otherwise }\end{array}\right.$$

$$h(y)=g^{-1}(y)$$

Then :

$$\begin{aligned} f_{\vec{Y}}(\vec{y}) &=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\right)^{n}\|A\|^{-1} \exp \left[-\frac{1}{2} \vec{y}^{\top}\left(A^{-1}\right)^{\top} A^{-1} \vec{y}\right] \\ &=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\right)^{n}\|\Sigma\|^{-1 / 2} \exp \left[-\frac{1}{2} \vec{y}^{\top} \Sigma^{-1} \vec{y}\right].\end{aligned}$$

I am having trouble figuring out why $\left\|\sum\right\|^{2}=\|A\|$, or why $\left(A^{-1}\right)^{\top} A^{-1}=\sum^{-1}$. That is, how do we get the covariance matrix $\sum$  into the formulation for the multivariate standard normal of this transformation.

Or simply, why is $Var(\vec{Y}) = \sum=A A^{T}$  ... ?  Where does this result come from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This derivation may be what you are looking for:

$$
\Sigma_{Y}= E\left[YY^{T}\right]=E\left[AX\left(AX\right)^{T}\right]
$$
$$
\Sigma_{Y}= E\left[AXX^{T}A^{T}\right]=AE\left[XX^{T}\right]A^{T}=A\Sigma_{X} A^{T}
$$

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was missing. Overlooked the fact that $Var(\vec{x}) = 1$ and $E[A\vec{x}]=0$ for a multiivariate standard normal. Then, as you stated:

$$\operatorname{Var}(A \vec{x})=A \operatorname{Var}(\vec{x}) A^{\top}$$


$\begin{aligned} \operatorname{Var}(A \vec{x})=E\left[A \vec{x}(A \vec{x})^{T}\right] &=E\left[A \vec{x} \vec{x}^{T} A^{T}\right] \\ &=A E\left[\vec{x} \vec{x}^{T}\right] A^{T} \\ &=A Var(\vec{x}) A^{\top} \\ &=A A^{T} \end{aligned}$

Comment: Still missing one parth though: where does the term $\|\Sigma\|^{\frac{1}{2}}=\|A\|$ or $\|\Sigma\|^{-\frac{1}{2}}=\|A\|^{-1}$   come from  in the density ? 

How does the square root of the absolute value of the determinant of the covariance matrix equal $||A||$ ?